# Using TextMate, is there a hotkey to move the cursor out of the quotations?

Tags: textmate

Using [TextMate](http://macromates.com/), I noticed when you open a new set of quotations, the ending quotation is automatically created and wraps what you are going to type. Let's say I am finished typing my string literal, and now my cursor in the position right before the ending quotation. I still need to write other things after the ending quotation. For example, I may be writing a parameter for a function, and the function has a few more parameters. I know `CMD + ENTER` goes to the next line, and I know `CMD + SHIFT + ENTER` ends the current line with a semi-colon and then moves the cursor to the next line. Is there a similar natured hotkey that moves the cursor to the position after the ending quotation? I understand that I can just press `'` and then `SPACE`, and that I can use the arrow keys, but I want to know if there is a hotkey with similar a similar nature. Also, for future reference, I feel like I can never find all these hotkeys that I maybe look for. Where am I supposed to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give any examples, but if this is your use case:

```
somefunction("onestring", "otherstring")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^abc^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then you're asking for a hotkey to move your cursor from position **ab** to **bc**, which can be accomplished by hitting <kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow key) once. Any hotkey combination would result in more key-presses than this and therefore not be beneficial (unless you want to avoid moving your hand off the home position, in which case you may want to look at [ViMate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tm-vi-plugin/)).

For finding hotkeys the Textmate bundle contains a function called **Show Keyboard Shortcuts**, which lets you do exactly that. Hit <kbd>^⌥⌘K</kbd> to quickly access it.

Comment: That was the thing, it was efficient because I had to move my hand off the home row.

Answer (score 2):

Currently using:
TextMate version 2.0-alpha.9547

Was trying to define it myself when I found out it is already defined as:

Ctrl + f